# c# DropDown Menu Background Removal

Tags: c#

I have been having a look at the net trying to find an answer but came up unlucky.
I am trying to make a Dropdown search Bar for my application but would like to to be just plain. I can't seem to find a way to remove all the background just leaving the text box by itself.

**This is an example of what I have --**

[image: DropDown Menu with background]

**This is an example of what I want--**

[image: DropDown Menu with no background]

I just want to know if the is a way to remove the bits to the left and right.

Any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coc62.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH5Uw.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the `BackColor` Property of your `ToolStripMenuItem`.  In your case, change it to `White`.